# Is it possible to upload videos using primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I searched a lot to find an example of uploading videos using primefaces but no lock. Primefaces uses
allowTypes to specify the data type. If it's possible to upload videos what extensions could be uploaded?
here is a snippet that uploads images.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p:fileUpload
mode="advanced"
fileUploadListener="#{uploaderBB.handleFileUpload}"
allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|PNG|GIF|JPG|JPEG)$/"
auto="true"/>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this line and now it's working just fine.

```
 allowTypes="/(\.)(mp4|avi|flv)$/"
```